# Вернуть или отфильтровать новый массив объектов Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
[
    {
      "datadoc_prih": "2021-02-05 20:00:00",
      "summ_prih": "22420.00",
      "summv_prih": "17550.00",
      "kod_doc": "020045"
    },
    {
      "datadoc_prih": "2021-02-01 16:28:21",
      "summ_prih": "4969.00",
      "summv_prih": "2527.61",
      "kod_doc": "040041"
    },
    {
      "datadoc_prih": "2021-02-02 16:29:04",
      "summ_prih": "1530.00",
      "summv_prih": "729.49",
      "kod_doc": "040041"
    },
    {
      "datadoc_prih": "2021-02-01 16:30:11",
      "summ_prih": "1150.00",
      "summv_prih": "525.01",
      "kod_doc": "040041"
    },
]
```

Подскажите как вернуть новый массив объектов проходящих по условию где `datadoc_prih` содержит `2021-02-01` и `kod_doc` = `040041`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вкратце:

```
arr.filter(el => el.datadoc_prih.includes('2021-02-01') && el.kod_doc === '040041');
```

Чуть длиннее:

```
let getSmth = (arr, datadoc_prih, kod_doc) => arr.filter(el => el.datadoc_prih.includes(datadoc_prih) && el.kod_doc === kod_doc);

let filteredArr = getSmth(arr, '2021-02-01', '040041');
```

---

```js
let arr = [
    {
      "datadoc_prih": "2021-02-05 20:00:00",
      "summ_prih": "22420.00",
      "summv_prih": "17550.00",
      "kod_doc": "020045"
    },
    {
      "datadoc_prih": "2021-02-01 16:28:21",
      "summ_prih": "4969.00",
      "summv_prih": "2527.61",
      "kod_doc": "040041"
    },
    {
      "datadoc_prih": "2021-02-02 16:29:04",
      "summ_prih": "1530.00",
      "summv_prih": "729.49",
      "kod_doc": "040041"
    },
    {
      "datadoc_prih": "2021-02-01 16:30:11",
      "summ_prih": "1150.00",
      "summv_prih": "525.01",
      "kod_doc": "040041"
    },
];


let getSmth = (arr, datadoc_prih, kod_doc) => arr.filter(el => el.datadoc_prih.includes(datadoc_prih) && el.kod_doc === kod_doc);

let filteredArr = getSmth(arr, '2021-02-01', '040041');
console.log(filteredArr);
```