# Oтфильтровать новый массив объектов PHP

Tags: php

```
[
    {
      "datadoc: "2021-02-05 20:00:00",
      "summ_prih": "22420.00",
      "kod": "020045"
    },
    {
      "datadoc": "2021-02-01 16:28:21",
      "summ_prih": "4969.00",
      "kod": "040041"
    },
    {
      "datadoc": "2021-02-02 16:29:04",
      "summ_prih": "1530.00",
      "kod": "040041"
    },
    {
      "datadoc": "2021-02-01 16:30:11",
      "summ_prih": "1150.00",
      "kod": "040041"
    },
]
```

Подскажите как вернуть новый массив объектов проходящих по условию где datadoc содержит 2021-02-01 и kod = 040041

Comment: а чего на js (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1245673/191482) не устроило?)))

Comment: Нужно было такое же реализовать на php )

Comment: Ответ написал. если помог - можно ткнуть галочку и стрелочку))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$arr = [
    [
      "datadoc" => "2021-02-05 20:00:00",
      "summ_prih"=> "22420.00",
      "kod"=> "020045"
    ],
    [
      "datadoc" => "2021-02-01 16:28:21",
      "summ_prih" => "4969.00",
      "kod" => "040041"
    ],
    [
      "datadoc" => "2021-02-02 16:29:04",
      "summ_prih" => "1530.00",
      "kod" => "040041"
    ],
    [
      "datadoc" => "2021-02-01 16:30:11",
      "summ_prih" => "1150.00",
      "kod" => "040041"
    ],
];

$getfilteredData = function($arr, $datadoc, $kod) {
    return array_filter($arr, function($item) use ($datadoc, $kod) {
        return strpos($item['datadoc'], $datadoc) !== false && $item['kod'] === $kod;
    });    
};

$filteredData = $getfilteredData($arr, '2021-02-01', '040041');

//-----------------------------
print_r($filteredData);
//-----------------------------
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [datadoc] => 2021-02-01 16:28:21
            [summ_prih] => 4969.00
            [kod] => 040041
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [datadoc] => 2021-02-01 16:30:11
            [summ_prih] => 1150.00
            [kod] => 040041
        )

)
```